# Using both http-server and node express server

Tags: node.js, express, server, httpserver

I've seen the following setup for a node express server:

**server.js**

```
import { Server } from 'http'; 
import Express from 'express'; 

const app = new Express(); 
const server = new Server(app);
```

Since it is possible just to run express directly, what is the advantage here of returning the express server as an argument of the http server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Express is a request handler for an HTTP server.  It needs an HTTP server in order to run.  You can either create one yourself and then pass `app` as the request handler for that or Express can create it's own HTTP server:

```
import Express from 'express'; 
const app = new Express();
app.listen(80);
```

But, just so you fully understand what's going on here.  If you use `app.listen()`, all it is doing is this (as shown from [the Express code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615)):

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

which is just creating its own vanilla http server and then calling `.listen()` on it.

---

If you are just using a plain vanilla http server, then it saves you some code to have Express create it for you so there's really no benefit to creating it for yourself.  If, you want to create a server with some special options or configurations or if you want to create an HTTPS server, then you must create one yourself and then configure it with the Express request handler since Express only creates a plain vanilla http server if you ask it to create it yourself.  So, create one yourself if you need to create it with special options.

Comment: The practice of creating a separate `http.Server` is very widespread (for example. the [`socket.io` example code](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) does it as well). I guess that a lot of people see that and think that that's how it should be done.

Comment: @robertklep - There's nothing wrong with creating your own http server manually.  Express just offers a shortcut that will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks that helps. So in that case, it's redundant to explicitly create an http-server?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it's _wrong_, it's just extra code :) And I've seen it cause issues, by people calling `app.listen()` instead of `server.listen()`, and not realizing that they started a _new_ HTTP server, instead of the one represented by `server`.

Comment: @Paulos3000 - It's not redundant.  Somebody has to create one.  You either create one yourself or you ask express to do it for you.  But, it does save code to have Express do it for you.  Note, if you are, for example, trying to instantiate and https version of your server, then Express can't do that for you so you'd have to create your own http server manually.

Comment: I don't mean it doesn't do anything, I just mean it's superfluous code, surely? I guess it's not a big deal either way, just want to be sure there's no tangible advantage of explicitly creating your own, so I can do away with it!

Comment: @Gimby - I added info about that.